# In Maxima, how do I get the elementwise (Hadamard) product of two matrices?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, maxima

In Maxima, how do I get the elementwise (Hadamard) product of two matrices?

e.g

```
a b
c d

* 

e f
g h 

->

a*e b*f
c*e d*h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A*B *is* the elementwise product, as opposed to the matrix product, A.B